# How to Smoothly Prevent a Fixed Element from Scrolling Past A Specified Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, positioning

Essentially what I want to do is keep my blog posts' meta information on the screen at all times. As it is, the meta info (title, author, etc.) is displayed to the left of the post content, and I have it set up where the meta information stays on screen smoothly when I scroll down. However, I'm having an issue:

I can't get it to smoothly *not* scroll over the #comments DIV. It either overlaps or is jumpy, depending on how I tweak the code.

Here is the JS function I'm using:

```
function brazenlyScroll() {
    var element = jQuery(".single-post .headline_area");
    var top = element.offset().top - 50;
    var elementHeight = 26 + element.height();
    var maxTop = jQuery("#comments").offset().top - elementHeight;
    var scrollHandler = function() {
        if (jQuery(document).width() > 1035) {
            var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if (scrollTop<top) {
                element.css({position:"relative",top:""})
            } else if (scrollTop>maxTop) {
                element.css({position:"absolute",top:(maxTop+"px")})
            } else {
                element.css({position:"fixed",top:"50px"})
            }
        }
    }
    jQuery(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
    jQuery(window).resize(scrollHandler);
    scrollHandler();
}
```

That code is included via an external JS file and is called at the bottom of the page. You can see all of this in action here: http://www.rickbeckman.org/dumber-and-dumber-and-dumber/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the comments div shrink to right by giving it a 300px padding when meta block reaches maxTop.

Comment: I don't want to shrink the comments block. The meta block should stop scrolling altogether when it reaches the bottom of its container DIV.

The scrolling issue effects horizontal scrolling when the window is shrunk down enough to cause it. The post content moves behind the meta information. I need the meta block to have a definite width that is absolute or relative and a vertical spacing that is fixed, I guess. I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested ur code and was able to fix the overlapping by changing 26 to a bigger number, say about 60.

var elementHeight = 26 + element.height();

Hope this helps.